# Train tesseract OCR tess4j on a new font

Tags: java, opencv, tesseract, javacv

i am using [tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/%E2%80%8E) and javacv for recognizing and reading the plate number
i have car images containing lebanese plate number which a 6 number and one letter
tess4j is not recognizing my nummbers correctly so i want to train tess4j in order to recognize my numbers
after trying the sample in of tess4j i recognized that images must of resolution 300 dpi and character width and height between 10 px and 40 px
how can i make convert my image to this resolution with this width and height character
or is there any other solution that can give an accurate result